# How to take a bio with a pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram.raw import functions

api_id = 
api_hash = ""
TARGET = -


app = Client("my_account")
async def main():
    async with app:
        # для парсинга группы
        async for member in app.get_chat_members(TARGET):
            print(member)
            break
app.run(main())
```

This code parses the group into users
But when I parsed there is no user bio

```
{
    "_": "ChatMember",
    "status": "ChatMemberStatus.MEMBER",
    "user": {
        "_": "User",
        "id": ,
        "is_self": false,
        "is_contact": false,
        "is_mutual_contact": false,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "is_bot": false,
        "is_verified": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_scam": false,
        "is_fake": false,
        "is_support": false,
        "is_premium": false,
        "first_name": "",
        "status": "UserStatus.RECENTLY",
        "dc_id": 2,
        "photo": {
            "_": "ChatPhoto",
            "small_file_id": "AQADAgADJL8xG4zb8EgAEAIAA8e130cBAAPa3NiUo0I8QwAEHgQ",
            "small_photo_unique_id": "AgADJL8xG4zb8Eg",
            "big_file_id": "AQADAgADJL8xG4zb8EgAEAMAA8e130cBAAPa3NiUo0I8QwAEHgQ",
            "big_photo_unique_id": "AgADJL8xG4zb8Eg"
        }
    },
    "joined_date": "2022-09-12 14:43:27"
```

Everything except bio
How can I find the bio preferably using id

You can even at a telethon if you want the main thing is that he takes a bio with the help of Id

Comment: That's because there is no such value in the [User object](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/User). You need `about` in [UserFull](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/types/user-full).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyrogram's [`User`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/User) object doesn't have a `.bio`, `.about` or similar.

You'll want to get a [`Chat`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Chat) object via [`get_chat()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat).
Alternatively you could [`invoke()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/invoke) the lower level ("Raw") method [`users.GetFullUser()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/functions/users/get-full-user) to get a [`raw.base.users.UserFull`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/types/users/user-full) constructor, in which `.full_user` is the needed [`raw.types.UserFull`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/types/user-full). That last object has an `.about`, which will be the bio of the user.

For more info on lower level / "Raw" methods, see Pyrogram's Documentation on [Advanced Usage](https://docs.pyrogram.org/topics/advanced-usage).